# How to clear the BindingList Comepeltly

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, list, binding

i've fill the binding list

So i want to clear it as fastest way as it can

so i have the binding list that has at least 2000 items

what is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use :

```
myBindingList.Clear()
```

As mentionned in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).